# how to select mysql in multi table and mix in one json?

Tags: php, mysql, json

This is my first table

```
SELECT * FROM tb_chat WHERE senderid = "1"
```

output:

```
  {  
     "id":"5",
     "itemid":"43",
     "senderid":"1",
     "receiverid":"11",
     "sendtime":"2015-10-04 23:31:35",
     "sendcontent":"1232342sdfsasg",
     "remark":null
  }
```

This is my second table

```
SELECT * FROM  `tb_user` WHERE id =  "1"
```

output

```
{  
    "id":"1",
    "username":"hksfho",
    "password":"ae6e16c74efb51b616b0d4f7151aff88",
    "email":"ho@hksf.hk",
    "installationId":"E705A03522F3E85768581A7222AC40F6"
}
```

I want to mix two tables in to one json using php
the tb_chat.senderid = tb_user.userid

[image]

Comment: Show us your effort what you have tried so far? For this you have to iterate second query one by one and merge it with its parent. Or if you are using any `ORM` this is easy to achieve.

Comment: @MahaDev the picture that I want to output

Comment: $final_result = new array();
$final_result = $query1_result; 
$final_result['senderid'] = $query2_result;

json_encode ($final_result);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NO Code so a logical answer is provided , do your stuff as below-

```
$result =mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query(SELECT * FROM tb_chat WHERE senderid = "1"));
$result2 =mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query(SELECT * FROM  `tb_user` WHERE id =  "1"));
$result["senderid"]=$result2;
echo json_encode($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

So, if you get the result of query in `json` format, you can turn it into arrays, merge them and make it to json format again. **BUT** it has big overhead:

```
json_encode(array_merge(json_decode($firstResult, true),json_decode($secondResult, true)))
```

So, I think you `should` get the result of query in `array`, id depends what ORM you use, of whatever, how to do this.